# Count numbers of a power number

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have a power number $((a^b)^c)^d$. I want to know how many number will be produced if the terms $a,b,c,d$ will run from $1$ to $n$.
Can anyone help me a general formula to calculate myself, or a result with $n$, say, $16$?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem? By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [ask], on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply talking about how many numbers *can* be produced, then there are $n$ possible values for each of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. In that case there are $n^4$ possibilities but this answer does not consider distinct numbers and will count duplicate numbers more than once.

If you want distinct numbers, then we can find combinations with $b$, $c$, and $d$: $\begin{pmatrix} n\\3\end{pmatrix}$ for a total of $n\cdot\begin{pmatrix} n\\3\end{pmatrix}$ possibilities.

But this is still a limited answer as it does not consider factors of the combinations nor the fact $1^n=1$ for any $n$.

Comment: I know this isn't a complete answer but thought I would get the ball rolling.
@OnnixTim Can you clarify what you are actually looking for? Perhaps give a simple example solution for n=2 or n=3?

Comment: "then there are n possible values for each of a, b, c, and d. In that case there are $n^4$ possibilities."  How do you know these are distinct and that no $((a^b)^c)^d = ((a'^{b'})^{c'})^{d'}$.  In fact they are obviously not disting $16^1 = 4^2 = 2^4$ so $((2^4)^c)^d = ((4^2)^c)^d = ((16^1)^c)^d$ and even wors $((2^1)^4)^d = ((2^2)^2)^d= ((2^4)^1)^d= (2^4)^d)^1$ etc.  this is *way* over count.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for your comment and sorry for the confusion. I did mean exactly that in my first paragraph which is why I started my second paragraph with "If you want distinct numbers..." but I see how that could be confusing for a first pass reading. I will edit my answer to clarify that and avoid any further confusion. Thanks!

Comment: What I am actually looking for to be quantity of possibilities, not values. Thank for your answer.